# Can I Know the Reasons why any of my question is downvoted

Tags: support

Recently three of my questions were downvoted by some reader. Is it possible to know the reasons for the down vote - to re-frame the question. The questions are:

[**Before Aruna, who was the Sun God's Charioteer?**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21085/before-aruna-who-was-the-sun-gods-charioteer)

[**Who was Sanjaya?**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/who-was-sanjaya)

[**Kamba Ramayana with English commentary.**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21088/kamba-ramayana-with-english-commentary)

why did the User / Users feel these questions deserved a down vote?

Comment: Meta is not a place to enquire about the reasons for downbote. If we don't know who is the downvoter, how will we answer your question? It will be only speculations. Questions inviting speculation are not welcome on a meta sites. BTW, the general reason could be unclear and lack of research effort. Nothing more than that.

Comment: After quick glances on the Qs, none of them seemed worthy of getting downvoted..but one of the Qs is very very long.. :D and for Sanjaya u should not have asked for references from the Srutis.. but anyways i do not think that was the reason..